# How to "make something" in a specific time and day of the week in java?

Tags: java, date, time, schedule

I have an application that needs to play some specifics audios(mp3) periodically. Let me give one example: Every Monday at 8:00am -> hello.mp3.
How can I do that in Java??
I´m trying using Calendar, JodaTime, but I cant do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends, if you are using Java EE, you can use EJB Timer. And there is always Quartz http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Comment: Quartz is very effective for this. I've seen it employed on a small scale and a large scale, and it's good for both and fairly easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a scheduled task. Timer class can provide this for you. Here is an example to get you started [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm)

Answer (score 0):

What a `Timer` can help you to achieve is so minimum, [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) is a well-known (and easy-to-use) scheduler that accepts cron-like expression.

If you use Spring in your application, it has a [scheduling module](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz) that can keep your Quartz code even cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `java.util.Timer` to define schedules and `java.util.TimerTask` to define job. You can also use well-known Quartz Scheduler.

If you use Spring, you can use its scheduling service (it can be configured to use either Quartz Scheduler or `java.util.Timer` in its work).

If you run desktop App, the easiest way is to use  `java.util.Timer`. For more complicated schedules use Quartz Scheduler.